# Why are NVRAM-N DIMMs Reliant on RDIMMs within Dell PowerEdge Servers?

Tags: memory, hardware, dell-poweredge

Hardware questions! Watching some tech reviews about the newest and bluest Dell Poweredge servers and I noticed in [this link](https://www.itcreations.com/user-manuals/R740XD/nvdimm.pdf) that NVDIMM's for the new Dell Poweredge 740XD servers require R-DIMM's to operate properly. Why can't NVRAM-N DIMM's simply operate independently on the board? (What's preventing Dell from supporting say 1 NVRAM-N DIMM per CPU Socket and nothing else? How are R-DIMM's that different beyond the backup capability?) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current operating system implementation of NVDIMM-Ns shows this memory as a block device (ie storage) where you typically mount a filesystem and use it as a regular (but really fast) disk.

See *Dell EMC NVDIMM-N Persistent Memory*, [chapters 8 & 9](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/poweredge-r740_user's%20guide3_en-us.pdf).

So you still need RAM for the OS.

Comment: Oh ok that makes a lot more sense, will there be implementations for NVRAM-N as a memory instead of storage solution?

Comment: Ultimately, you will need to organise data in this persistent storage. Files (and therefore file system) is a convenient way to do it. So I'm not sure that another implementation/semantic is needed at all. And you can still `nmap`a file located in nvdimm should your application require persistent memory.

And remember this principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file (not sure this applies to Windows, but it definitely does for Unix/Linux)